# Node.js - The multi part could not be bound

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an error `(node:1152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): RequestError: The multi-part identifier "SC1.refb" could not be bound.`

In console log show all select but it seems that comes to the last and gives the error.

My code:

```
return Promise.all(parts.map(function(part) {
          console.log("SELECT sc.scstamp, st.u_posic, st.fornec, st.fornecedor, sc.ref, sc.qtt, sc.design FROM sc INNER JOIN st  ON st.ref = sc.ref WHERE sc.refb = '"+kitRef+"' AND st.u_posic = '"+part.u_order+"'"+
          "UNION SELECT SC2.scstamp, st.u_posic, st.fornec, st.fornecedor, SC2.ref, SC2.qtt, SC2.design FROM sc AS SC1"+
          "INNER JOIN sc SC2 ON SC2.refb = SC1.ref INNER JOIN st  ON st.ref = SC2.ref WHERE SC1.refb = '"+kitRef+"' AND st.u_posic = '"+part.u_order+"'");
            return request.query("SELECT [sc].[scstamp], [st].[u_posic], [st].[fornec], [st].[fornecedor], [sc].[ref], [sc].[qtt], [sc].[design] FROM sc INNER JOIN st  ON st.ref = sc.ref WHERE sc.refb = '"+kitRef+"' AND st.u_posic = '"+part.u_order+"'"+
            "UNION SELECT [SC2].[scstamp], [st].[u_posic], [st].[fornec], [st].[fornecedor], [SC2].[ref], [SC2].[qtt], [SC2].[design] FROM sc AS SC1"+
            "INNER JOIN sc SC2 ON SC2.refb = SC1.ref INNER JOIN st  ON st.ref = SC2.ref WHERE SC1.refb = '"+kitRef+"' AND st.u_posic = '"+part.u_order+"'")
            .then(function(articles) {

                return {part:part, articles:articles};
            });
        }));
```

The query is ok because if i put it in sql works well.

Thank you

Comment: add a `.catch(function(e){ console.log(e) })` chained after the `.then`

Comment: give me error on SC1.ref and SC1.refb . What is the problem? @stecb

Comment: @user3242861 can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: it was a space in query. Solved! Thank you @stecb

Comment: @user3242861 you need to seriously consider the advice in the answer below about sql injection

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have some whitespace messed up in the SQL but **that is the least of your problems here.**

First of all, **always attach a rejection handler** to every promise or otherwise your app will crash on errors. Example:

Bad:

```
f().then(function (articles) { ... });
```

Good:

```
f().then(function (articles) { ... }, function (error) { ... });
```

Also good:

```
f().then(function (articles) { ... }).catch(function (error) { ... });
```

See this answer to know why it's important:

- [Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)

Second of all, **never concatenate strings with SQL** or otherwise you will get SQL injection vulnerabilities. Example:

Bad, unsafe, error prone and hard to maintain:

```
connection.query(
  "SELECT * FROM player WHERE nick = '" + data.login + "' AND pass = '" + data.pass + "'",
  function (err, rows) {
    //...
  }
);
```

Good, safe, robust and easy to maintain:

```
connection.query(
  "SELECT * FROM player WHERE nick = ? AND pass = ?",
  [data.login, data.pass],
  function (err, rows) {
    // ...
  }
);
```

See those answers for more details:

- [How to escape mysql special characters with sockets.io/node.js/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312239/how-to-escape-mysql-special-characters-with-sockets-io-node-js-javascript/43312492#43312492)
- [cannot use backtick when using nodejs 7.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429068/cannot-use-backtick-when-using-nodejs-7-3-0/41431242#41431242)
- [Node js - Promise Rejection Warning when process a lot of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155046/node-js-promise-rejection-warning-when-process-a-lot-of-data/42158207#42158207)
- [Is it possible to listen for object instantiation in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526203/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-object-instantiation-in-node-js/27526698#27526698)

Obligatory comic strip that demonstrates the problem:

[image]