# NodeJS mysql sync query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I want to run sync query in nodejs like this...

```
for (var i in data){

conn.query("Select 1 from user where userid="+data[i].id,function(err,row){
     Rows.push(row);
});

}

console.log(Rows);
```

In this code block my rows all time going to null... I want to run sync query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not be able to use such a function synchronously in the thread-blocking sense (nor should you!) but you may get close to that if you use a promise version of the database connection (using Bluebird's promisifyAll or a specific promise version of mysql driver available on npm) and the new async/await syntax (or generator-based coroutines for platforms older than Node 7.x where async/await is not available - another option is to use Babel for transpilation).

Example - you would be able to use a code like this:

```
for (var i in data) {
  let row = await conn.query("Select 1 from user where 
  userid="+data[i].id);
  Rows.push(row);
}
console.log(Rows);
```

But if it can be run in parallel then something like this would be more efficient and shorter:

```
let Rows = await Promise.all(data.map(item =>
  conn.query("Select 1 from user where userid=" + item.id));
console.log(Rows);
```

For more details on that topic, see:

- [Do async in a blocking program language way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973850/do-async-in-a-blocking-program-language-way/43976255#43976255)
- [Using async/await + Bluebird to promisifyAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096728/using-async-await-bluebird-to-promisifyall/43096840#43096840)
- [try/catch blocks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await/40886720#40886720)
- [Using acyns/await in Node 6 with Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299393/using-acyns-await-in-node-6-with-babel/42299652#42299652)
- [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)

Note - it can be use only inside of functions declared with the `async` keyword.

**Word of warning:** your code may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use placeholders instead of strings concatenations in your SQL. I didn't fix that aspect of your code - see those answers for more details:

- [cannot use backtick when using nodejs 7.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429068/cannot-use-backtick-when-using-nodejs-7-3-0/41431242#41431242)
- [Node.js - The multi part could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320056/node-js-the-multi-part-could-not-be-bound/43322265#43322265)
- [How to escape mysql special characters with sockets.io/node.js/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312239/how-to-escape-mysql-special-characters-with-sockets-io-node-js-javascript/43312492#43312492)
- [Node js - Promise Rejection Warning when process a lot of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155046/node-js-promise-rejection-warning-when-process-a-lot-of-data/42158207#42158207)
- [Is it possible to listen for object instantiation in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526203/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-object-instantiation-in-node-js/27526698#27526698)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bluebird` `npm` `module` to solve this. use `npm install bluebird` to install `bluebird`

```
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    var Rows= [];
    data.forEach(function (obj) {
       conn.query("Select 1 from user where userid="+obj.id,function(err,row){
               Rows.push(row);
       });
      });
       return Promise.all(Rows);
    })
```

Comment: This will not work. You are returning `Promise.all(Rows)` in a forEach callback, which is run once for every iteration with its return value ignored. Besides, you're running `Promise.all` on an array that doesn't contain promises. What is it supposed to do, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use async module.

```
var async= require('async')
async.eachSeries(arr, function(index, callback){
  conn.query("Select 1 from user where userid="+index, 
    function(err,res) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      }else{
       Row.push(res);
      }
    callback();
});
},function(err){
  if(err)
   return err;
   console.log("all queries executed")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper that returns a Promise. Using `await` you can make it sync:

```
function promiseWrapper() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.query("SQL_QUERY", queryCallback(resolve, reject);
    }
}

function queryCallback(err, row){
    return (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(row);
    }
}
```